# How to get the name of the widget holding the currently selected text? (QTextCharFormat)

Tags: c++, qt

A text editor app has multiple widgets, of multiple types: `QTextEdit`, `QTableView`, `QTreeView`. All of them need to have rich text editing functions.

This code enables the strikethrough function to work on just ONE specific widget. How to make it work on any widget that holds the currently selected text?

`ui->toDoListTextEdit` needs to be replaced with a call to the widget that holds the selection `fmt`, or the `cursor`?. How to do this, considering that there are three different types of widgets?

```
void MainWindow::on_actionStrike_triggered()
{
    //put in strikethrough
    QTextCharFormat fmt;
    fmt.setFontStrikeOut(true);

    //blend selection
    QTextCursor cursor = ui->toDoListTextEdit->textCursor();
    if (!cursor.hasSelection())
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    cursor.mergeCharFormat(fmt);
    ui->toDoListTextEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(fmt);

}
```

Comment: Right now, `on_actionStrike_triggered` is a classic toolbar action. So it is a private `SLOT` of `MainWindow`. I'm not certain how to connect it to all the widgets, especially considering that the app might grow and there might be 20+ editable widgets in different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MVC pattern, create own model which will store text to display, subclass from QTextView and emit signals to change model's data(text), same goes to model, implement signals to change custom QTextView class.